# how to get <li> from <ul> with tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul id="chapters">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
var a = $("#chapters li");
```

How do I get the variable `a` so as it contains the following result:

```
a = "<li>One</li>    <li>Two</li>    <li>Three</li>"
```

Comment: `$("#chapters').html()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are you sure? As far as I know, Jquery returns alsway an array if you search after elements.

Comment: @reporter now that the question has been edited to give a clear goal, then yes that appears the case. Initially the question was just code with no explanation, other than the title

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to get the HTML contents of `#chapters`.

You are going to use

```
$("#chapters").html()
```

```js
var a = $("#chapters").html();
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="chapters">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

You could also remove the newlines and trim the whitespace to get the exact result:

```
$("#chapters").html().replace(/\n/g,'').trim();
```

```js
var a = $("#chapters").html().replace(/\n/g,'').trim();
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="chapters">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = $('#chapters').children( $('li'))
console.log(a.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="chapters">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

You can use jQuery childer method.

```
$('#chapters').children( $('li'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#chapters').find('li')
```

This should do the trick.